# SQL check if the value of one row is bigger than the next row

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write an SQL query, that searches in stock of a shop, where there is sold more coca cola than pepsi, this is the query and result i currently have:

```
SELECT Verkoop.item_id, Verkoop.item_name, Verkoop.shop_name, SUM(Verkoop.sold) as WinkelTot
FROM(
    SELECT tbl_items.item_id, tbl_items.item_name, shop_name, sold
    FROM tbl_stock
    NATURAL JOIN tbl_shops
    NaTURAL JOIN tbl_items
    ORDER BY sold DESC) AS Verkoop
WHERE Verkoop.item_name LIKE "%Coca Cola%" OR Verkoop.item_name LIKE "%Pepsi%"
GROUP BY   
    CASE
        WHEN Verkoop.item_name LIKE "%Coca Cola%" THEN 'Coca Cola'
        WHEN Verkoop.item_name LIKE "%Pepsi%" THEN 'Pepsi'
    END,
    Verkoop.shop_name
ORDER BY shop_name DESC
```

CURRENT RESULT:

```
item_id       i tem_name          shop_name       shop_sold
  41      Pepsi Cola 6X1.5L    TREKK Zaventem       566
  40      Coca Cola  6X0.5L    TREKK Zaventem       1662
  41      Pepsi Cola 6X1.5L    TREKK VLBR2          1292
  40      Coca Cola  6X0.5L    TREKK VLBR2          1478
  39      Coca Cola 6X1.5L     TREKK Landen         630
  41      Pepsi Cola 6X1.5L    TREKK Landen         1402
  42      Pepsi Cola 6X0.5L    TREKK Hola           1672
  40      Coca Cola  6X0.5L    TREKK Hola           862
  42      Pepsi Cola 6X0.5L    TREKk Antwerpen3     874
  40      Coca Cola  6X0.5L    TREKk Antwerpen3     895
  39      Coca Cola 6X1.5L     TREKk Antwerpen2     390
  42      Pepsi Cola 6X0.5L    TREKk Antwerpen2     1230
```

So this query returns all pepsi and cola articles, with their corresponding shop and sells.

Now I would like to compare each row with their pepsi variant.

NEEDED RESULT:

```
  shop_name         more_cola_than_pepsi
 TREKK Zaventem            yes
 TREKK VLBR3               yes
 TREKK LANDEN              no
 TREKK Hola                no
 TREKK Antwerpen3          yes
 TREKK Antwerpen2          no
```

Anyone might know how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Query is related to `Mysql` and why have tagged `Sql Server`.

Comment: You are clearly not using SQL Server, because it (happily) does not support `NATURAL JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *do not* use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is simply broken.  It joins tables based on columns with the same name, so a small change to the definition of either table could break a query.  It even ignores explicit foreign key references.

Second, you are using `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  This is another dangerous practice, and, in this case, is totally superfluous.

The query you want can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sh.shop_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_name LIKE '%Coca Cola%' THEN st.sold ELSE 0 END) as Coke,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_name LIKE '%Pepsi%' THEN st.sold ELSE 0 END) as Pepsi,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_name LIKE '%Coca Cola%' THEN st.sold ELSE 0 END) > 
                  SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_name LIKE '%Pepsi%' THEN st.sold ELSE 0 END)
             THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no'
        END) as CokeMoreThanPepsi
FROM tbl_stock st JOIN
     tbl_shops sh
     USING (<appropriate columns here>)
     tbl_items i
     USING (<appropriate columns here>)
WHERE i.item_name LIKE '%Coca Cola%' OR i.item_name LIKE '%Pepsi%'
GROUP BY sh.shop_name
```

Comment: This was indeed what I was searching for, Thanks!